# Methods to handle uneven censoring for the monitoring of composite endpoints

Tags: survival, cross-correlation

Suppose you are doing a cancer study and you compare progression-free survival (PFS) for two groups. A PFS event is either death or disease progression (PD), which ever comes first. People in the study might be censored for PD but not death. This is when we don't know if or when PD happens, but we might know if and when they die.

What methods are out there for handling this case? My thought is that an unbiased but inefficient analysis might censor at the time of last PD screen. But what if the person is known to be alive after that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is how to define PFS, not statistical question.

Comment: @user158565 I disagree, but are you asking for a formal treatment of the question, i.e. with notation and variables? Or more general language? The statistical question is clear to me, and I could offer an answer, but I'm not familiar with the literature.

Comment: I think the search term for which you are seeking is competing risks or Fine Grey model.

Comment: My understanding of your question is: Let X be PD time, Y survival time, Z PFS time. (+ means right censoring). Define Z by Z=X if PD not censoring, no problem. if X=x+, and Y=y, then Z=x+, or y, or y+? If X=x+ and Y=y+, then Z=x+, or y+?

Comment: @mdewey I'm not sure how the Fine & Grey model would lead to an efficient and unbiased estimate of the HR of PD *and* death (the composite endpoint). Usually familiar with using it to estimate the subdistributional cause-specific hazard ratios... can you say more?

Comment: I missed that point in your question so my comment is mis-guided. I will leave it though as it may help to clarify it for others.